# Python - Trying to truncate, write to and then copy the written-to file to another file

Tags: python, file, powershell

This is the Python code I have written for this purpose:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, filenamefrom, filenameto = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filenamefrom
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filenamefrom,'w+')

print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write('%r\n%r\n%r\n' % (line1, line2, line3))

print "Now we are going to copy %r to %r!" % (filenamefrom, filenameto)



readdata = target.read()
openfilenameto = open(filenameto,'w+')
openfilenameto.write(readdata)


print "And finally, we close it."

openfilenameto.close()
target.close()
```

Now when I run this in Powershell, this is what comes up:

```
We're going to erase 'test.txt'.
If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C).
If you do want that, hit RETURN.
?
Opening the file...
Truncating the file. Goodbye!
Now I'm going to ask you for three lines.
line 1: h
line 2: h
line 3: h
I'm going to write these to the file.
Now we are going to copy 'test.txt' to 'test4.txt'!
And finally, we close it.
```

However - once I run:

```
cat test4.txt
```

In Windows Powershell, this is what it outputs - nothing after the following line, although that empty space goes down the Powershell page 34 lines after the following line:

```
PS C:\python27> cat test4.txt
```

I have tried changing the file mode modules between 'r+' and 'w+' throughout the Python code, but that doesn't work.

Also - I know this is annoying and repetitive code, but I am quite new to this and am still building my skills in shortening code. Apologies for that and I appreciate the patience of any of you who may reply.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you don't separate your `read` and `write`.

After you write your buffer to the file, your file-pointer is at the end of the file. If you use `read()` again, you tell the file descriptor to read from that point, i.e. from the end of the file. Of course there is nothing to read… So you get nothing at all ;-)

Try to separate your write/read or put the file descriptor to the beginning again (with `seek`) and you're done.

Also use the `with` statement to simplify your code and bring related lines together.

Here is the updated script with a somewhat better solution:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, filenamefrom, filenameto = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filenamefrom
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "Opening the file..."
with open(filenamefrom, 'w+') as target_file:
    print "Truncating the file. Goodbye!"
    target_file.truncate()
    print "I'm going to write these to the file."
    target_file.write('%r\n%r\n%r\n' % (line1, line2, line3))

print "Now we are going to copy %r to %r!" % (filenamefrom, filenameto)

with open(filenamefrom, 'r') as target_file:
    readdata = target_file.read()
    with open(filenameto, 'w+') as to_file:
        to_file.write(readdata)
```

However, there are better ways to copy a file, for example:

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(filenamefrom, filenameto)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time Septi - for your explanation and an updated script.